# FCMPlugin is not defined

Tags: cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2.

I am trying to using firebase push notification function, and i have followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/1wU9N7VxoS8 for my device end program and https://youtu.be/oPCiDtzUcTo for my serve side.

And i have deployed it in a real device, but the notification arrives only once in the notification tray, the first time i log in. After that it stops, only if i delete my messages and pushtoken collection from my database, it will run, which is also once.

Then i had try to run it in the browser, but in the console log their was a message of FCMPlugin is not defined. I have tried removing the declare keyword, removing phonegap plugin, used the native ionic plugin, but no luck.

Help would be a divine mercy for me. (:

**Solution:**
first, check the cordova plugin list using `cordova plugin list` in your app directory and check whether their is phonegap plugin. Using FCM plugin with the phonegap cause this error. Delete it and you are good to go.

Comment: i think maybe because cordova is for phones...and you havent installed an npm package for it....also here is an FCM package from ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/

Comment: show relevant code

Comment: I have solved it. I had tried removing the phonegap plugin again as mentioned in [http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-sending-push-notifications-to-specific-devices-part-1/](http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-sending-push-notifications-to-specific-devices-part-1/) and deployed the app in my mobile, now it works.

Comment: @Ace Could you please add an answer explaining how you were able to solve the issue, and then accept it so we can close the issue? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** first, check the cordova plugin list using cordova plugin list in your app directory and check whether their is phonegap plugin. Using FCM plugin with the phonegap cause this error. Delete it and you are good to go.